# Change column title for a view but not modify column name in the list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a similar problem as explained in this link:
[How to change column title for a view, but not modify the list?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50004/how-to-change-column-title-for-a-view-but-not-modify-the-list)

But I am not good at work in SharePoint Designer.

How can I open a view page in Designer Mode?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 or 2013?

Answer (score 4):

I hope that you want to change a column header like following.

[image]

So you can accomplish it by using JsLink. Just override the `OnPreRender` like following

```
OnPreRender: function(ctx) {
    var fileName = ctx.ListSchema.Field[1];
    fileName.DisplayName = "File Name";
}
```

By above code I am changing the first column's header. So my after view is looking now like following

[image]

My full code is given below

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

  function getBaseHtml(ctx) {
    return SPClientTemplates["_defaultTemplates"].Fields.default.all.all[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.FieldType][ctx.BaseViewID](ctx);
  }

  function init() {

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

       OnPreRender: function(ctx) { 
       var fileName = ctx.ListSchema.Field[1];
      fileName.DisplayName = "File Name";
       },

      Templates: {

      //     View: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Header: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Body: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Group: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Item: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //     Fields: {
      //         "<field internal name>": {
      //             View: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //             EditForm: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //             DisplayForm: function(ctx) { return ""; },
      //             NewForm: function(ctx) { return ""; }
      //         }
      //     },
      //     Footer: function(ctx) { return ""; }

      },

      // OnPostRender: function(ctx) { },

      ListTemplateType: 101

    });
  }

  RegisterModuleInit(SPClientTemplates.Utility.ReplaceUrlTokens("~siteCollection/Style Library/change-title.js"), init);
  init();

});
```

**I asked you a question in comment but you did not bother to reply. JsLink is only available is SharePoint 2013.**

For SharePoint 2010 see [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50004/how-to-change-column-title-for-a-view-but-not-modify-the-list/58090#58090)

Comment: sorry i lost connection to the internet for 16 hours ago................................ i use sharepoint 2010

Comment: then follow this answer http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/58090/21421